# How to solve Half Duplex/Full Duplex issue

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, duplex

I'm really struggling here. Completely non-technical and trying to set up a Source Connect connection on my Macbook Air. I have an ethernet to USB-C adapter that is flashing amber on one side, solid green on the other. It appears to send data but not receive it, so it's running on half-duplex I assume (after a lot of googling!). My Mac appears to be configured to Full Duplex, but when we look at my router configuration, there's apparently supposed to be an area where it refers to negotiation, and there isn't. I just have no idea how to fix this! I don't know if I have a faulty adapter, but I doubt it because I'm getting internet through it alone (wifi is currently switched off), so I'm at a loss. Anyone out there have any ideas?!

Answer (score 1):

The Ethernet adapter's LEDs usually do not mean "send" and "receive". Instead, *one* LED is a combined "activity" light for both sending & receiving, while the other LED indicates general status of the link, e.g. "green for 100Mbps / orange for 1Gbps" (or the other way around). So it's normal to see only one blinking, the other one should remain steady.

If you have Internet access – or even just if the computer was able to automatically get an IPv4 address – then the adapter *is* able to send as well as receive data.

---

"Half-duplex" means you can send *and* receive – just not at the same time. (That is, only one device can talk at a time, others must wait.) Very old Ethernet types worked this way, whereas modern switched Ethernet is full-duplex and allows both sides to talk at once. Wi-Fi is also half-duplex.

(If a connection is strictly one-way and can *only* send, or only receive, that's "simplex".)

Usually your devices should not be manually configured for either mode *at all* – that is, they should be allowed to auto-configure the Ethernet mode. Auto-negotiation is practically mandatory for Gigabit Ethernet, and it's not surprising that your router won't let you switch it off.

(The manufacturer might have omitted the option because in home networks it's very rarely necessary, and easy to cause problems. For example, if one side is expecting auto-negotiation, but the other is set to a manual speed/duplex mode, then the first device will give up and choose some default parameters which might not match what the other one was set to.)